# SQL Case when condition more than

Tags: sql

I have `product` and `agegroup` table.

I'm joining these two tables on match of `id` from `agegroup` table and `agegroup` from the `product` table.

The query I'm using is here;

```
WITH CTE_AgeGroup AS                                                                            
                (
                SELECT  p.agegroup,
                      CASE
                             WHEN AgeFromMonths >=0 AND AgeToMonths <= 24 
                               THEN
                                    CASE 
                                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=0 AND AgeToMonths <= 3 THEN '0-3 Months'
                                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=3 AND AgeToMonths <= 6 THEN '3-6 Months'
                                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=6 AND AgeToMonths <= 9 THEN '6-9 Months'
                                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=9 AND AgeToMonths <= 12 THEN '9-12 Months'
                                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=12 AND AgeToMonths <= 18 THEN '12-18 Months'
                                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=18 AND AgeToMonths <= 24 THEN '18-24 Months'
                                          END  
                           END as  'age'
                FROM agegroup a inner join product p on
                a.id= p.agegroup

                ),
                  CTE_AgeGroupResultSet AS
                (
                   select
                        Age, Count(*) AS CountAge from CTE_AgeGroup  group by Age   
                      )
                select * from CTE_AgeGroupResultSet order by age;
```

However, my problem is that if product A  is listed in '0-3 months', and product B is listed om '3- 6 months', these two products are not get listed in '0-24 months'.

I want modify my query so that Product A and B are also get listed in '0-24 months'

Answer (score 1):

You might use [with rollup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213225%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in group by to get grand count:

```
WITH CTE_AgeGroup AS
(
    SELECT p.agegroup,
           CASE WHEN AgeFromMonths >=0 AND AgeToMonths <= 24 
                THEN CASE WHEN AgeFromMonths >=0 AND AgeToMonths <= 3 
                          THEN '0-3 Months'
                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=3 AND AgeToMonths <= 6 
                          THEN '3-6 Months'
                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=6 AND AgeToMonths <= 9 
                          THEN '6-9 Months'
                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=9 AND AgeToMonths <= 12 
                          THEN '9-12 Months'
                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=12 AND AgeToMonths <= 18 
                          THEN '12-18 Months'
                          WHEN AgeFromMonths >=18 AND AgeToMonths <= 24 
                          THEN '18-24 Months'
                      END  
            END as 'age'
    FROM agegroup a 
         inner join product p 
            on a.id= p.agegroup
),
CTE_AgeGroupResultSet AS
(
    select case when grouping (Age) = 1 then '0-24' else Age end Age, 
           Count(*) AS CountAge 
      from CTE_AgeGroup
     group by Age WITH ROLLUP
)
select * 
  from CTE_AgeGroupResultSet 
 order by age;
```

Also, if you add a varchar column to agegroup containing group description you will eliminate case altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you go for this case functions.
It would be better to use 
UNION operator(this just takes the union of both your product and agegroup tables)

FULL OUTER JOIN(joins both the tables and takes data from both tables even if there are NULL values in both tables.)

Comment: I gone for case statements, since the label used in when statements were my required static filters. that is why.